# aren't my hobby / aren't my hobbies

Tags: nouns, auxiliary-verbs

How is better to express this thought idiomatically and which one isn't grammatically correct?

> **Watching movies isn't my hobby.**
>
> **Movies aren't my hobby.**
>
> **Movies aren't my hobbies.**
>
> **Movies aren't my cup of tea.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are grammatically correct.

I'm not sure that going to watch movies can be described as a hobby.  It's too passive.  Certainly you can't say that each movie is a different hobby.  So 3 doesn't make sense.  1 and 2 are equivalent through a contextual understanding of "what you do with movies is watch them". But I don't think "hobby" is the right word.  4 is a bit dated.  I might say it but I can't imagine a teenager using "not my cup of tea" except ironically.

Comment: **Movies aren't my thing.** Is it better to say?

Comment: Yes, that's a nice casual expression.  or "I'm not really into movies"